# I am having problems trying to copy files in linux with python (I also get analogous inconsistencies when i switch to Windows 10)

Tags: python, subprocess

Python = 3.6.8 System= Ubuntu
Problem:  I want to copy using subprocess but i cant get it to work.
I am using the shutil module first and it works, then with the subprocess module it doesnt.
can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong ?? thanks

```
>>> s
'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll'
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows'
>>> dest=os.getcwd()
>>> shutil.copy(s,dest)
'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/libmad.dll'
>>> subprocess.call('cp {} {}'.format(s,dest))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call('cp {} {}'.format(s,dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 287, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cp /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows': 'cp /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows'''
```

Then if i do this

```
>>> subprocess.call('cp {} {}'.format(s,dest),shell=True)
1
```

I get a 1 as a return value from the above and no file is copied. So far i can only copy with shutil. Why is this happening?...do i have to randomly try 10 commands just copy one file ? ....i must be doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] any details into the question itself. Comments are often deleted.

Comment: please dont give negative stars to new people otherwise it doesnt encourage them to use this service because they dont get reputation points.

Comment: Please make sure your questions are useful. I downvoted because you were putting content in comments, which isn't helpful to future users. If you want your posts to be received positively, you need to make sure that they are of good quality. That is your responsibility when posting here. I've undone it now because it was mostly fixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your arguments as a list and pass them to `run()` like `subprocess.run(['cp',src,dst])`

You can read up more on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) of subprocess module

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string or path-like object. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, **it is recommended to pass args as a sequence**

Comment: This worked...thanks very much, but if you could be kind enough because i am a newbie , if you go here, you will see people telling us to use subprocess.call https://stackabuse.com/how-to-copy-a-file-in-python/  ...isnt that what i did ???? put everything in a big string ???? The documentation to me is hard to follow....like "it is recommended to pass args as a sequence "...meaning ? a list?..why dont they just say a list...these documentations suck.

Comment: @LucyLu See my updated answer, which should answer the question you had in this comment, and more accurately address your question rather than providing an alternate solution to the final goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your error states the problem:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cp /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows': 'cp /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll /home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows'''
```

I'm not familiar with the {} {} syntax, but it looks like it is pulling in your variable s:

```
'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll'
```

and there are some issues with some combination of spaces and string literals. This is causing what you want to be executed as a shell command to interpreted as just one giant string. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) out for a similar issue.

Edit: I recreated this and verified that it is caused by the spaces in the directory you have stored in `s`. You need to add escape character to each space. Change your assignments of `s` and `dest` to be:

```
s = '/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install\ files\ for\ Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll'
dest = '/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install\ files\ for\ Windows/'
```

Alternatively, you could use raw strings, in which spaces have no significant meaning. See further info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=literals#string-and-bytes-literals)

```
s = r'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/SoxFiles/libmad.dll'
dest = r'/home/godzilla/Desktop/SoX/Install files for Windows/'
```

Windows and linux handle spaces in directories quite differently, so this is likely what is causing your OS based issues. Having them as raw strings is likely the safest bet to work on both OSes, but I may be wrong (test both syntax out.)

Comment: That's one way to go, but in Windows, I've had trouble doing that for system directory names. Some directories (such as user names) can have spaces, and be quite difficult to change later, thus this is not always an option. Thus, although this is a temporary solution what you've done, if you want your code to be applicable in various OSes and handle common errors like this, then you should likely just generate your strings as raw strings.